# How to connect input box to ajax call to fetch json or xml

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax, xml

I want to create a search bar that can fetch data from a url as xml or json then decode it and show particular part portion that i want. But main thing i also want to connect input field value integrated in url thats all so it can fetch data according to the input. Any help....Thank you in advance

This is a simple w3schools code that fetch data from xml file. I have just added a input tag and want it pass as a parameter in file name...like if the file name is this "cd_catalog.xml", it will fetch data from "cd_catalog.xml?q=keyword". Keyword here is the input field value

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search">
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Get my CD collection</button>
<br><br>
<table id="demo"></table>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_xml2

Comment: we can only help u when there's a code we can view

Comment: I have Updated my question now please suggest